# Finite dimensional Lie algebras with trivial homology

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

Are there any known examples of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ such $H_*(\mathfrak{g})=0$ for all $*>0?$ Better still are there such algebras that this condition holds for arbitrary coefficient modules and not just for the trivial one?

I think the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ should be semisimple. Outside of this, I don't know anything. I don't know even how to start answering the question.

Edit: Correcting the initial ambiguity of my question, I assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: "I think the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak g$ should be semisimple." Not sure what meaning of "semisimple" you are using here, but if $\mathfrak g \neq 0$ is *any* Lie algebra over *any* field, then the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak g)$ is *never* artinian, and *always* has trivial Jacobson radical. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615836/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I mean the following definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings. It is equivalent to having global dimension 0 I think

Comment: Well that one is stronger than being artinian. As said, for any non-trivial Lie algebra over a field, the universal enveloping algebra is not artinian and hence not semisimple in this definition. This is true at least as soon as PBW applies, so this holds even for many Lie algebras over rings which are not fields.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well, I am clearly missing something obvious. I thought that if $\textrm{gl.dim}=0$ then there is no non-zero homology of a trivial module $k$ above degree 0. However, I think there are still Lie algebras with non-trivial $H_*(\mathfrak{g};k).$

Comment: Well the global dimension is not $0$ ... Are you maybe thinking in the opposite direction than the one we should? By the way, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087301/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Wikipedia article on global dimension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_dimension mentions that ring is semisimple iff its global dimension is 0. That applies to commutative rings or Noetherian rings. I am fairly certain that $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ is Noetherian (for finite dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$ anyways)

Comment: As I have said several times now, $U(\mathfrak g)$ is not semisimple for nonzero $\mathfrak g$, so if what you say holds, its global dimension is not $0$. From what I can tell that matches what both answers say too.

Comment: Maybe we have misunderstood each other all the time. If your argument is "If what I want holds, then $U$ has global dimension $0$ and hence is semisimple" then that is correct, and together with what I say ("but for nonzero $\mathfrak g$, $U$ is not semisimple") provides an alternative proof that what you want forces $\mathfrak g$ to be $0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Oh, yes, that is a neat observation:)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{g}$ has dimension $n<\infty$, then

- either $\mathfrak{g}$ is unimodular (i.e., the linear form $T:x\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{ad}(x))$ vanishes), and then $H_n(\mathfrak{g})\neq\{0\}$ (it is 1-dimensional)
- or $\mathfrak{g}$ is not unimodular, and then $T$ is a nonzero homomorphism from $\mathfrak{g}$ to the ground field, so $H_1(\mathfrak{g})\neq 0$.

In characteristic zero we have another alternative: if $\mathfrak{g}\neq\{0\}$:

- either $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable, and then $H_1(\mathfrak{g})\neq 0$;
- or $\mathfrak{g}$ is not solvable, and then $H_3(\mathfrak{g})\neq 0$. Indeed, $\mathfrak{g}$ admits a nonzero semisimple Lie algebra as a retract (Levi factor), and the result follows ($\ast$) from the nonvanishing of $H_3(\mathfrak{g})$ when $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple (Chevalley-Eilenberg).

($\ast$) Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ a retract of $\mathfrak{g}$ (i.e., a subalgebra such that there exists a homomorphism $p:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ such that $p\circ i=\mathrm{id}_\mathfrak{h}$, where $i$ is the inclusion. Then the canonical map $i_*:H_n(\mathfrak{h})\to H_n(\mathfrak{g})$ is injective for all $n$. Proof: Since $H_n(-)$ is functorial, we have $p_*\ast i_*$ equal to the identity of $H_n(\mathfrak{h})$, so that $i_*$ is injective.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm always nitpicky with trivial cases and was aware of $n=0$ in the first statement, which is correct for $n=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've added details.

Answer (score 2):

For finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebras we have the following result by Whitehead.

*Theorem (Whitehead)*: If L is a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero and
$M$ is a nontrivial irreducible module, then
$$
H^i(L,M)=H_i(L,M)=0
$$
for all $i\ge 0$.

For the trivial module Whitehead's result is not true. We have
$H^1(L)=H^2(L)=0$, but $H^3(L)\neq 0$ by a result of Chevalley and Eilenberg in $1948$. By Poincare-duality (semisimple Lie algebras are unimodular) we also obtain a non-zero third homology group.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, by the way, is the converse statement true to a some degree? That is, are all such algebras direct limits of semisimple ones?

Comment: Wait for a second, I just understood, that you are actually not answering my question. The first requirement of mine was that homology with trivial coefficients vanishes.

Comment: I think it is not possible (except for trivial cases) that $H_i(L)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$.

Comment: Even if an algebra is infinite-dimensional? Basically, that was my question. Is every algebra with $H_i(\mathfrak{g})=0$ for $i\ge 1$ trivial?

Comment: Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras are a different world. You should decide in the post whether you mean finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional Lie algebras (these are two different questions, I think).

Comment: There is a homology vanishing result for Kac-Moody algebras by [Kumar](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjbqqb0rdH0AhV77rsIHdmeBV04ChAWegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkumar.math.unc.edu%2Fpapers%2Fkumar08.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3cpetp0jDiPfrj0xwTfNM5), but the module seems again to be non-trivial. For the trivial module, the authors says that "the situation is drastically different from Whitehead". So I suppose that again the Lie algebra has to be trivial, but I don't know if this is known.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. I will modify my question to explicitly say that algebra should be finite-dimensional.